# How to send id of clicked element with route

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send the id of the clicked element in the sidebar to this `DokumentiScreen` page with routes.
Here is on tap method.

```
     onTap: () {
         print('sublink pressed');
         Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(child['link']);
         /Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DokumentiScreen()));
```

And this is route used.

```
 '/dokumenti/:id': (ctx) => const DokumentiScreen(),
```

And I'm getting this error :

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/dokumenti/11", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
```

Hope anyone can help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Navigate to Next Screen

```
static void goToNextScreen(BuildContext context, var uId) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: 
  (BuildContext context) {
      return NextScreen(uId);
    },));
  }
```

In Next Screen

```
class NextScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    var uId;
    NextScreen(this.uId);
    @override
   _NextScreenState createState() => _NextScreenState();
 }

class _NextScreenState extends State<NextScreen> { 
    var uId;

   @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     uId = widget.uId;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold()
 }

}
```